# "Хоть шарОм покати", ударение

Tags: орфоэпия

Почему ударение на О? Почему так сложилось?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А. Зализняк. Труды по акцентологии, Том 1, c.493

> Слово *шар* обнаруживает отчётливую тенденцию к следующему акцентному
>   разграничению: схема С в обычных (относительно более абстрактных)
>   значениях, схема B в значении "круглый предмет (например, для игры)".
>   Так, например: *объём шАра, со всего земного шАра* (возможно только
>   такое ударение), но в бильярде обычно "*шарА*", шарОм и т.д. (причём
>   не только в сочетания типа *загнать шарА, загнуть шарА, два шарА*,
>   которые часто приводятся в этой связи, но и в других контекстах); ср.
>   также выражение *хоть шарОм покати*.

На мой взгляд, концепция "более абстрактного" не объясняет разграничения между такими реалистичными случаями, как "бильярдным шарОм" и "воздушным шАром" (равно "земным"). Возможно, значение имеют и размеры реального или даже мнимого предмета относительно человека, т.е. можно ли таким шаром "покатить" или проголосовать.

Answer (score 7):

В книжке Вернера Лефельдта "Акцент и ударение в русском языке" писано учёно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, налицо отклонение от акцентной схемы. Почему? - идиома, обсуждению не подлежит.

Предположены две версии отклонения ударения.

Первая - "бильярдная", ударение на последний слог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вторая - жутко занимательная, но никем не поддержанная...

> Возможно, выражение "шаром покати" не имеет отношения не только к
>   биллиарду, но и к шару. По-польски szary (шАры) или szarak (шАрак) -
>   заяц-русак (буквально - "серый, серяк"). Возможно, исходное выражение
>   звучало как "Choc' szarym skaczi" (хоть зайцем скачи) и первоначально
>   описывало ровное пустое поле. При переносе в русский "szarym" было
>   воспринято как "шарОм"...

Ещё из Энциклопедии бильярдиста:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]